# Handling Facebook access token expiry in Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook Javascript SDK http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ to authenticate and approve my Facebook app.
My SDK code will be as follows:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({
        appId : 'MY_APP_ID', 
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml : true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth : true
    });

    FB.login(function(response) 
    {
        if (response.authResponse) 
        {
            var userFBAccessToken  =  response.authResponse.accessToken;
            console.log('userFBAccessToken: ' + userFBAccessToken);
            FB.api('/me', function(response) 
            {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                    console.log('Logged out.');
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'user_activities,user_notes,user_photos,user_videos,user_status,offline_access'});
};  

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

I am confused with offline_access deprecation. My questions here are, if I enable the 'Deprecate offline access' option in my App Advanced settings page:

1. What will be the expiry time of the access token which I received from response.authResponse.accessToken. Whether its 2 hours or 60 days? (what will be the duration for now and after May 1st 2012)
2. If its only 2 hours, how can I extend it to 60 days?
3. Whether the retrieved access token will be valid only when users are in online or it will be valid even when they are offline?

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone please answer for the above questions? Thank you.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on this, despite the answer.  Looks like the javascript sdk requires you to do it server-side still, since it requires the app secret.  After you do this and return it to the client, how do you 'make it stick' (let the browser know about the new accesstoken the next time FB.init is called)?  Also, the iOS sdk extends it automatically.  How?  You don't supply your app secret to  the iOS SDK at any point.  How can facebook reliably know this is an iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1+2. The expiry will be 2 hours. You will need to extend it after it expires. The request for extension is explained here under 'Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint':
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

1. Should be valid at all times.

Comment: Any code example for extending the access_token? Can it be done with the current Facebook PHP SDK?

Comment: There is an example for the extension request in the url. Obtaining an access token via the PHP SDK grants you an access token for two months automatically.